# Need to count the number of a specific day between two dates IE number of Fridays from the begining of the current month to now() in excel vba

Tags: excel, date, dayofweek, vba

I would like a textbox, "txtWeek," to show the number of Fridays or Thursdays between the beginning of the month to the current date, IE I have started with

```
Dim MyDate, MyStr
    MyDate = Format(Now, "M/d/yy")
    Me.txtDate.Value = MyDate
Dim Day As Variant
    ReDim Day(2)
    Day = Array("Thursday", "Friday")
    ComboBox1.ColumnCount = 1
    ComboBox1.List() = Day
Dim X, AsDate
    X = Format(Now, "M/1/yy")
If Me.ComboBox1.Text = "Friday" Then
    Me.txtWeek.Value = Int((Weekday(X - 6) - X + Me.txtDate.Value) / 7)
Else
End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

**Requirements:**

1. To show in Textbox `txtDate` the date of the machine
2. To calculate the number of Fridays or Thursdays in the month of `txtDate` till the date of the machine
3. To show in Textbox `txtWeek` the number of Fridays or Thursdays as per prior point

**Assumptions:**

1. The `Sheet1` of the workbook containing the procedures has two `TextBoxes` and one `ComboBox`
2. The Procedures will be triggered by the change events of the `ComboBox`, when user select the weekday to count

**Copy this procedure in the Code Module of `Sheet1`** - *Change Event for the ComboBox*

```
Private Sub CmbBox1_Change()
Dim sWkDy As String
Dim dDte1 As Date
Dim bDayC As Byte
Dim bThu As Boolean, bFri As Boolean

    Rem Set Weekday
    sWkDy = Me.CmbBox1.Value
    Select Case sWkDy
    Case "Thursday":    bThu = True
    Case "Friday":      bFri = True
    Case Else:          Exit Sub
    End Select

    Rem Set First date of the current month
    dDte1 = 1 + WorksheetFunction.EoMonth(Date, -1)

    Rem Counts the weekdays
    bDayC = Dte_Days_Count_To_Today(dDte1, blThu:=bThu, blFri:=bFri)

    Rem Set Current Date in `txtDate`
    'Using format `mmm-dd-yyyy` to ease reading of the date independently of the format (American or International)
    Me.TxtDate.Value = Format(Date, "mmm-dd-yyyy")  'change as required

    Rem Set count of weekdays `txtWeek`
    'Using this format to directly show the weekdays counted
    Me.TxtWeek.Value = "Count of " & sWkDy & "s: " & bDayC 'change as required

End Sub
```

**Copy these procedures in a standard module**

```
'Ensure these Keywords are at the top of the module 
Option Explicit
Option Base 1
```

This procedure sets the available options in the `Combobox` – *Run this first, need to run only once*

```
Private Sub CmbBox1_Set()
Dim aWkDys As Variant
aWkDys = [{"Thursday", "Friday"}]
    With Me.CmbBox1
        .ColumnCount = 1
        .List() = aWkDys
    End With
End Sub
```

This Function counts the numbers of days from the date entered as input date `dDteInp` to the actual date of the machine `TODAY`. The results are generated using arithmetic calculus and avoids the loop trough each of the dates in the range. It also gives the option to count various weekdays at once e.g.: to count Thursdays and Fridays from a given date till today call it this way `Call Dte_Days_Count_To_Today(dDteInp, blThu:=True, blFri:=True)`

```
Public Function Dte_Days_Count_To_Today(dDteInp As Date, _
    Optional blSun As Boolean, Optional blMon As Boolean, _
    Optional blTue As Boolean, Optional blWed As Boolean, _
    Optional blThu As Boolean, Optional blFri As Boolean, _
    Optional blSat As Boolean)
Dim aDaysT As Variant, bDayT As Byte    'Days Target
Dim bDayI As Byte                       'Day Ini
Dim iWeeks As Integer                   'Weeks Period
Dim bDaysR As Byte                      'Days Remaining
Dim bDaysA As Byte                      'Days Additional
Dim aDaysC(7) As Integer                'Days count

    Rem Set Days Base
    aDaysT = Array(blSun, blMon, blTue, blWed, blThu, blFri, blSat)
    bDayI = Weekday(dDteInp, vbSunday)
    iWeeks = Int((Date - dDteInp + 1) / 7)
    bDaysR = (Date - dDteInp + 1) Mod 7

    Rem Set Day Target Count
    For bDayT = 1 To 7
        bDaysA = 0
        aDaysC(bDayT) = 0
        If aDaysT(bDayT) Then
            If bDaysR = 0 Then
                bDaysA = 0
            ElseIf bDayI = bDayT Then
                bDaysA = 1
            ElseIf bDayI < bDayT Then
                If bDayI + bDaysR - 1 >= bDayT Then bDaysA = 1
            Else
                If bDayI + bDaysR - 8 >= bDayT Then bDaysA = 1
            End If

            Rem Target Day Total
            aDaysC(bDayT) = iWeeks + bDaysA

    End If: Next

    Rem Set Results - Total Days
    Dte_Days_Count_To_Today = WorksheetFunction.Sum(aDaysC)
End Function
```

Suggest to read the following pages to gain a deeper understanding of the resources used:

[Option keyword](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278518(v=office.15).aspx), 
[Variables & Constants](http://www.excelfunctions.net/VBA-Variables-And-Constants.html), 
[Data Type Summary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251528.aspx),

[Optional keyword](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251696(v=office.15).aspx), 
[Function Statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264233(v=office.15).aspx), 
[For...Next Statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/gg251601.aspx),

[If...Then...Else Statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/gg251599.aspx), 
[Control and Dialog Box Events](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/ff838805.aspx),

[Select Case Statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/gg278665.aspx),
[WorksheetFunction Object (Excel)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff834434.aspx)

Answer (score -1):

This UDF will count the number of whatever day you pass into it, between two dates passed as longs.

```
Public Function HowManyDays(Sdate As Long, Edate As Long, Wday As Long)
Dim i
Dim MyCount As Long
For i = Sdate To Edate
    If Weekday(i) = Wday Then MyCount = MyCount + 1
Next i
HowManyDays = MyCount
End Function
```

Wday represents the day of the week, eg. sunday=1, monday=2... etc.
I don't know if it changes to monday=1, tuesday=2 etc. on other systems, or if it's always sunday=1.

With this UserForm code, a textbox will show the number of anyday depending on the value in a combobox:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim Sdate As Long, Edate As Long, Wday As Long

Sdate = CLng(DateSerial(Format(Now, "yy"), Format(Now, "mm"), 1))

Edate = CLng(Now)

Select Case ComboBox1.Value

    Case "Sunday"
        Wday = 1
    Case "Monday"
        Wday = 2
    Case "Tuesday"
        Wday = 3
    Case "Wednesday"
        Wday = 4
    Case "Thursday"
        Wday = 5
    Case "Friday"
        Wday = 6
    Case "Saturday"
        Wday = 7

End Select
TextBox1.Value = HowManyDays(Sdate, Edate, Wday)


End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

Dim Day As Variant

ReDim Day(7)
Day = Array("Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday")
ComboBox1.ColumnCount = 1
ComboBox1.List() = Day


End Sub
```

The start date is currently set to the first of the current month.

If you don't want to click a button to perform the action you can take the code from the CommandButton1_Click() and put it in ComboBox1_Change(), that way it will update the textbox whenever the combobox changes.

Comment: Any explanation to the downvote? This works perfectly fine for me.

Comment: I am getting a compile error for undefined "HowManyDays"

Comment: Have you implemented the Function from the top of my answer ?

Comment: Thank you that did work.  I have one more textbox, txtPayDays, that will display the number of Combobox1.Value Case, IE "5" Thurday's this month.

Comment: @EEM Thank you for all that.  I can't seem to get it to work.  No more errors but no results either.